# Mouse clicks stop working sometimes

Tags: windows-vista, mouse

I am having a serious issue with my mouse in which it will randomly not be able to click or cause other problems. Here is the breakdown:

- Sometimes, I can no longer left-click on many of my windows/taskbar (in order to focus them). Even though I can still left click on my desktop icons or the currently active window, I cannot focus any of the others.
- Other times, when I have a browser open, I will hit to go back one page and it will automatically go forward one page.

I know it's a mouse issue because this behavior stops when I unplug the mouse. Things will be fine when I plug the mouse back in, but eventually the behavior starts up again.

My mouse is a Razer Diamondback 3G and I am running Windows 7 Professional 32 bit. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "the behaviour stops when I unplug the mouse"? If the problem is related to behaviour of clicks, how are you testing "the problem" when the mouse is unplugged?

Comment: What are you "hitting" to go back one page? A mouse button or a browser button?

Answer (score 1):

Yup, it's a mouse issue. Did you drop it or something? How old is it? If it's a mechanical mouse, then it has more chances of getting broken on shocks, because it has more moving parts.

I think you cannot do much. Try cleaning the ball and the rollers (if a mechanical mouse) and the little hole with the light (if optical). Oh yes, also, try using a mouse pad. No matter what you use as the surface, it should be absolutely clean.

If nothing works, replace the mouse. You cannot do anything else.

Visit my tech blog, [Right Now In Tech](http://right-now-in-tech.blogspot.com). Suggest it to others and stay tuned to it, for many, many, fun tips and tricks.

Comment: "I can no longer left-click on many of my windows/taskbar (in order to focus them). Even though I can still left click on my desktop icons". Doesn't sound like it's just a mechanical issue.

Comment: Hey, but it could be a mouse button problem. You're using the computer. So, do you feel this could be the issue? Why don't you try plugging in another mouse and check if things work.

Answer (score 1):

Does the cursor/mousepointer lag behind your mouse movements?  If not, then the mouse is working properly and the problem is more likely to be driver-related.  Try removing the mouse device from the device manager: press **Windows-R** to bring up the **Run** dialog, enter **compmgmt.msc** and press **Enter**, navigate to **Device Manager**, find the mouse device, right-click on it and select **Uninstall**.  You should restart Windows after that.  On restart, Windows should re-detect the mouse and re-install and initialize the driver.  If that doesn't work, look for a recent driver on the mouse manufacturer's web site and install that.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any correlation between the applications are you using and the problem occuring?

It could be a rogue app stealing focus. 
Try opening task-manager when the problem starts; that will always regain focus (and allow you to select items on the task bar)

Are you using the drivers that came with the Razer Diamondback? Perhaps diagnose further using just the default windows mouse drivers. (Razor drivers are quite fully-featured and complicated and may be masking a problem).

Answer (score 0):

I had a Razer mouse that had screwy click sensitivity.  What I had to do was get the latest drivers from their site and use their application that comes with the driver installer to set the click sensitivity correctly on my machine.

Since your problem is occurring over time of use though, it appears as if your mouse is dying out on you.

Answer (score 0):

How (I *think*) I fixed left mouse button that sporadically freezes. In the past I'd go to task manager, simply hover over it until it was responsive, then left button on mouse would work fine. Tried everything. Finally out of desperation, went to settings, devices, mouse and turned off "scroll inactive windows when I hover over them". So far today, my left button hasn't suddenly and with no reason become unresponsive. Hope this is the fix to that annoying problem!